# trying to access API remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, iis-express

iam trying to access my api remotely but it does not connect

API using .net core and i run it with iis-express

i opened port on firewall to be allowed to access from remote device 
with this steps:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.42:58938/ user=everyone`

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=58938 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow`

in `applicationhost.config` i added

```
<bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:58938:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:58938:192.168.1.3" />


</bindings>
```

and in `launchSettings.json` i added application url like this:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
  //  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58938",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
```

I expected to be allowed to access my API from another device on the same network but i did not

Comment: Your `netsh` rule is for `192.168.1.42` but your `<binding>` is for `192.168.1.3`.

Comment: i changed both to ```192.168.1.3``` but still nothing reached